# ¿Comó enviar correos con AWS SES y Lambda con .NET CORE?

Tags: aws, .net-core, lambda, dotnetcore

Buenas tardes tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar una función lambda hecha en .Net Core,
Al momento de ejecutar en Mock Lambda Test Tool **(Visual Studio 2019)** ejecuta la función correctamente y envía el correo pero al momento de publicarlo y probarlo en aws lambda ahí es donde  me da un error. Adjunto el código y SS del resultado en Mock Lambda Test Tool y el error en AWS Lambda

```
public async Task<string> SendEmail(ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var msg = "";

            using (AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                var sendResult = new SendEmailRequest
                {
                    Source = "mailFrom",
                    Destination = new Destination
                    {
                        ToAddresses = new List<string> { "ToMail" }
                    },
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = new Content("Prueba desde net core"),
                        Body = new Body
                        {
                            Html = new Content
                            {
                                Data = htmlBody
                            }
                        }
                    },
                };
                try
                {
                    SendEmailResponse response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendResult);
                    msg = response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK ? "Se ah enviado con exito" : "No se ah enviado el correo";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    return msg = ex.Message;
                }

            };

            return msg;
        }
```

**Mensaje exitoso probado en visual studio Mock Lambda Test Tool**
[image: Resultado de la ejecución del codigo en Mock Test Test Tool]

**Error al momento de ejecutarlo en AWS Lambda**
[image: Error de la ejecución en AWS Lambda]

Comment: Para que la lambda pueda acceder al servicio SES necesitas darle los privilegios necesarios editando su rol. ¿Has hecho esa parte?

Comment: Si tiene permisos para Lambda, SES y también para CloudWatch ya que lo usare luego para que se ejecute cada x tiempo.

Comment: Entonces prueba a eliminar la llamada asíncrona. En una lambda como esta es un lastre totalmente innecesario

Comment: Fíjate que el cliente también te ofrece `SendEmail`, que a diferencia de la que tú usas, es una llamada síncrona

Comment: Gracias por el comentario ya intente y me indica que no es posible SendEmail Client inaccessible due to it's protection level.

Comment: me temo que te toca lidiar con los logs para ver dónde se está atascando la lambda. 3 segundos es demasiado tiempo para el código que tienes, es decir, que no creo que vayas a ganar mucho incrementando el tiempo

Comment: Si ya le di permisos al rol de Cloudwatch full para los logs pero me sigue sin escribirlos solo me indica el tiempo de inicio y final, ya puse varios debug para que escribiera en consola y que regrese el error pero aun nada.
Igualmente gracias por el apoyo. Saludos

Comment: si no escribe los logs es porque es parte no se ejecuta, sigue tirando del hilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema es el tiempo de ejecución de lambda tenia 3 segundos de espera lo aumente a 9 segundos y lo envía sin ningún problema.